# How to prove the exists of the function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It is my first time to ask a question here. I am studying mathematical analysis right now and I found difficulty in proving the question. Could anyone give me some hints or a prove of it. Thankyou

[image: Question]

Comment: As far as I can understand the question, they ask about existence of a specific value (denoted $w$ there) in the $[0,1]$ range, not about a _function_.

Comment: thank you for your reminding

Comment: But in the title you're asking _'How to prove the exists of **the function**'_, not 'how to prove the existence of a point/value/number'....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that each term on the right-hand side is a multiple of $w+1$. If you divide through by that, all of the $w$s end up on the left-hand-side. Define $g(w)$ as the resulting LHS and express the remaining $h$s on the right using $g$ instead.

Now you should be able to finish by using the Intermediate Value Theorem on $g$.

Comment: sorry  I still dont understand how to deal with  it after g(w) process

Comment: I got a constant function then apply intermediate Value Theorem is it correct ?

Comment: @pasu2601: If you're "getting a constant function", then you're either doing something wrong or (I suspect) misinterpreting the formula you produce. Note that $h$ can be _arbitrary_, so there's certainly no guarantee that either $h$ or $g$ will be constant. You ought to end up with something like $$ g(w) = \frac12g(0) + \frac13g\Bigl(\frac12\Bigr) + \frac16 g(1) $$ but this is _not a definition of $g$_, but is rather an _equation_ that your $w$ has to satisfy. It will be false for most $w$s, but your task is to show there is at least one $w$ it is true for.

Comment: I got it it seems that I misunderstand the question thank you